# A specific website shows white screen on my my android webview

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, android-webview

I am setting up an app that has a button which opens a specific website but this website shows white screen. I have copied the certificate from the website on the green padlock, created raw, XML, folders and pasted the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
       <domain includeSubdomains="true">andela.com</domain>
   <trust-anchors>
       <certificates src="@raw/cert_file"/>
   </trust-anchors>
```

But still no luck, any help?

Comment: Can you post the link of the website?

Comment: Https://www.andela.com/alc/